# Vector processing issues in multi threading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm implement about the data process in multi thread.

I want to process data in class DataProcess and merge the data in class DataStorage.

My problem is when the data is add to the vector sometimes occurs the exception error.

In my opinions, there have a different address class

Is it a problem to create a new data handling class and process each data?

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

using namespace::std;

static std::mutex m;

class DataStorage
{
private : 
    std::vector<long long> vecData;
public:
    DataStorage()
    {

    }
    ~DataStorage()
    {

    }
    void SetDataVectorSize(int size)
    {
        vecData.clear();
        vecData.resize(size);

     }
     
    void DataInsertLoop(void* Data, int start, int end)
    {
        m.lock();
        std::vector<long long> const * _v1 = static_cast<std::vector<long long> const *>(Data);
        
        long long num = 0;

        for (int idx = start; idx < _v1->size(); ++idx)
        {
              vecData[idx] = _v1->at(idx);

        }
        m.unlock();

    }



};
 class DataProcess
{
    
private:
    int m_index;
    long long m_startIndex;
    long long  m_endIndex;
    int m_coreNum;
     long long num;
    DataStorage* m_mainStorage;
    std::vector<long long> m_vecData;


public :
    DataProcess(int pindex, long long  startindex, long long endindex)
        : m_index(pindex), m_startIndex(startindex), m_endIndex(endindex),
        m_coreNum(0),m_mainStorage(NULL), num(0)
       
    {
       m_vecData.clear();
    
    }
    ~DataProcess()
    {

    }
    void SetMainAdrr(DataStorage* const  mainstorage)
    {
        m_mainStorage = mainstorage;
    }
    void SetCoreInCPU(int num)
    {
        m_coreNum = num;
    }
    void DataRun()
    {
        
        
        for (long long idx = m_startIndex; idx < m_endIndex; ++idx)
        {
            num += rand();
            m_vecData.push_back(num); //<- exception error position

        }

        m_mainStorage->DataInsertLoop(&m_vecData, m_startIndex, m_endIndex);
    }


};

int main()

{
    //auto beginTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    clock_t beginTime, endTime;
    DataStorage* main = new DataStorage();

    beginTime = clock();
    long long totalcount = 200000000;
    long long halfdata = totalcount / 2;
    std::thread t1,t2;
 

    for (int t = 0; t < 2; ++t)
    {
        DataProcess* clsDP = new DataProcess(1, 0, halfdata);
        clsDP->SetCoreInCPU(2);
        clsDP->SetMainAdrr(main);

        if (t == 0)
        {
            
            t1 = std::thread([&]() {clsDP->DataRun(); });
            
        }
        else
        {
            t2 = std::thread([&]() {clsDP->DataRun(); });
        }
    }


    t1.join(); t2.join();

   

    endTime = clock();

    double resultTime = (double)(endTime - beginTime);

   
    std::cout << "Multi Thread " << resultTime / 1000 << " sec" << std::endl;
    printf("--------------------\n");

   int value =  getchar();


}
```

Comment: There may be a language issue here, preventing this question from being _clear_.  You are asking -- if it is or is not a problem -- to create a new class and process data?

Comment: `::memcpy(&vecData+start, static_cast<std::vector<long long> const*>(Data), end-start);` looks all kinds of wrong. You're not copying the data the vector contains, you're copying the bytes of the vector itself.

Comment: @DrewDormann I want to create a new class and handle that class function in a thread. Is there anything wrong with it? Is it a problem that classes with different addresses are run separately?

Comment: @RetiredNinja  thank you for telling me. However, the function is not currently used and will be deleted, and we would like to start with a simple test.

Comment: This won't compile for me. `num1` and `num2` are undeclared.  There are several other warnings as well, you should make sure you have those enabled and pay attention to them when compiling.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Re-uploaded by correcting unnecessary code.  And the warning that is occurring is an arithmetic overflow, and I don't think the core problem is caused by that part.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any synchronization to protect against data races.

Comment: Data races aside, your compiler should be giving you [numerous warnings and errors about this code](https://godbolt.org/z/51GEoe1vG).

Comment: @RaymondChen In the DataProcess class, each one processes data, but there is no need for synchronization, right?
Isn't synchronization necessary when merging actual data?

Comment: @DrewDormann I re-edited the code and uploaded it to the above content.

Comment: Both threads are using the same `clsDP` because your lambda captures it by reference. When setting up the second thread, you reassign `clsDP = new ...`, which changes the value for both threads. Technically, the first thread's `clsDP` is destroyed at the end of scope, so you really have a "use of destroyed variable" bug. In practice, the memory for the first `clsDP` will be reused for the second thread, so both threads are now using the same `clsDP` object, and they crash while trying to fill the same `m_vecData`.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if none of your threads accesses portions of vecData accessed by another thread, DataInsertLoop::DataInsertLoop should not need to be synchonized at all.  That should make processsing much faster.   That is, after all bugs are fixed...  This also means, you should not need a mutex at all.

There are other issues with your code... The most easily spotted is a memory leak.

In main:

```
DataStorage* main = new DataStorage();  // you call new, but never call delete...
                                        // that's a memory leak.  Avoid caling
                                        // new() directly.
                                        //
                                        // Also: 'main' is kind of a reserved 
                                        // name, don't use it except for the
                                        // program entry point.

// How about this, instead ?
DataStorage dataSrc;  // DataSrc has a very small footprint (a few pointers).

// ...

std::thread t1,t2;   // why not use an array ?

// as in: 
std::vector<std::tread> thrds;

// ...
// You forgot to set the size of your data set before starting, by calling:
dataSrc.SetDataVectorSize(200000000);

for (int t = 0; t < 2; ++t)
{
    // ...

    // Calling new again, and not delete... Use a smart pointer type
    DataProcess* clsDP = new DataProcess(1, 0, halfdata);

    // Also, fix the start and en indices (NOTE: code below works for t < 2, but 
    // probably not for t < 3)
    auto clsDP = std::make_unique<DataProcess>(t, t * halfdata, (t + 1) * halfdata);

    // You need to keep a reference to these pointers
    // Either by storing them in an array, or by passing them to 
    // the threads.  As in, for example: 

    thrds.emplace_back([dp = std::move(clsDP)]() {clsDP->DataRun(); });
}

//...

std::for_each(thrds.begin(), thrds.end(), [](auto& t) { t.join(); });

//...
```

More...

You create a mutex on your very first line of executable code.  That's good... somewhat...

```
static std::mutex m;  // a one letter name is a terrible choice for a variable with 
                      // file scope.
```

Apart form the name, it's not in the right scope... If you want to use a mutex to protect DataStorage::vecData, this mutex should be declared in the same scope as DataStorage::vecData.

One last thing.  Have you considered using iterators (aka pointers) as arguments to DataProcess::DataProcess() ?  This would simplify the code quite a bit, and it would very likely run faster.

Comment: You sort of buried the lede. The root cause was the reference capture in the lambda, which you changed to a by-value move capture. The rest is tidying.

Comment: Sure, whatever.  Tracking memory properly does fix the issue instantly, though.

Comment: @RaymondChen:  I think the real issue is that the size of the source vector DatStorage::vecData was left uninitialized (SetDataVectorSize() is not called).  The passing by-reference would then pop up after that was fixed, and actual output data would be tested.

Comment: The pass-by-reference problem actually comes first, because the loop at the start of `DataProcess::DataRun` triggers UAF. Only after you survive that do we get to `DataInsertLoop` and the under-sized `vecData`.